# Trying to Use AppleScript to Convert .xls and .xlsx to .txt (Tab Delimited), Needs Fixing

Tags: macos, mac, microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, applescript

I copied this from an answer I got from another thread. I am trying to convert ~300 .xls and .xlsx files to tab delimited. They are all in the same folder. If anyone knows a better way, please let me know.

```
property type_list : {"XLS6", "XLS7", "XLS8", "XLSX"}
property extension_list : {"xls", "xlsx"}


on open these_workbooks
repeat with k from 1 to the count of these_workbooks
    set this_item to item k of these_workbooks
    set the item_info to info for this_item

    --this if statement tests to make sure the items you're converting are Excel spreadsheets and not folders or aliases
    if (folder of the item_info is false) and (alias of the item_info is false) and ((the file type of the item_info is in the type_list) or the name extension of the item_info is in the extension_list) then

        tell application "Finder" to open this_item

        tell application "Microsoft Excel"
            --this just tacks on ".txt" to your file name
            set workbookName to (name of active workbook & ".txt")
            --save the current open workbook as a tab-delimited text file
            tell active workbook to save workbook as filename workbookName file format text Mac file format
            close active workbook saving no
        end tell
    end if
end repeat
end open

on run
    display dialog "Drop Excel files onto this icon."
end run
```

All this does is open a dialog box and does nothing. Even though it's meant to be a droplet, nothing happens when I drag a file to it.

Answer (score 0):

We meet again. :)

Cut and paste the script into a new window in AppleScript Editor. When you save it, at the bottom of the window where it says "File Format," choose "application." This will enable the drag-and-drop feature.